# Hibernate: adjust multiple @OneToMany and ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate

I have three data class: `User`, `Site` and `SiteCredentials`. I want to adjust next behavior:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long userId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SiteCredentials> sites;
//other fields
}
```

---

```
public class SiteCredentials {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Site site;
//other fields
}
```

---

```
public class Site {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long siteId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "site")
    private Set<SiteCredentials> siteCredentials;
//other fields
}
```

I want to adjust next behavior:

1. Each time after user has been deleted: site credentials has to be deleted
2. Each time after site has been deleted: site credentials has to be deleted
3. Each time after site credentials has been deleted: no consequences for other entities
   Now I get an error: `update or delete on table "site_credentials" violates foreign key constraint "fkogfi5ft4imogbguv2jxjrishb" on table "users_sites"`. I know the reason but don't know how to fix it with entities adjust.

Comment: Please add the code where you perform the actual delete. Also, is there a reason `SiteCredentials` don't contain a `User` entity?

Comment: Without seeing the actual code which you use to execute the delete, I would assume that you do not synchronise the bidirectionally associated entities properly. I.e. if you delete an object of the class `SiteCredentials`, the corresponding object of the class `Site` might not get updated. Have a look at [this article of Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) on how to synchronise your entities in a bidirectional association.